# Kernel Photo Processing : Image Can't Appear

Tags: python, matplotlib, photoshop-script

I currently working on photo [image: this one], it use 3D matrices using python processing filtering (kernel). Currently my photo can't appear on the plot, it only appeared some cyan dots on the plot. What should I do to the script so my photo can appear on the plot. Thank you for answering.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im=plt.imread('NSX.jpg')
(dim_x,dim_y,dim_z)=im.shape
im1=np.pad(array=im, pad_width=[1, 1], mode='constant', constant_values=0)
im2=np.empty((652,1026,3))
ker1 = np.array([[1/9, 1/9, 1/9],
                [1/9, 1/9, 1/9],
                [1/9, 1/9, 1/9]])

def filtergambar():
    for m in range(0,dim_z):
        for i in range(1,dim_x-1):
            for j in range(1, dim_y-1):
                im_entry=im[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2]
                div=np.sum(im_entry*ker1)
                im2[i,j,m]=div
    return im2
filtergambar()
plt.imshow(im2.astyoe('uint8'))
plt.gray
plt.show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already some existing modules which can help you work with images, like ndimage and scikit-image to name but a few.

Here's your example using ndimage:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage as nd

im=plt.imread('NSX.jpg')

ker = 1/9 * np.ones((3, 3, 1))
im2 = nd.convolve(im, ker, mode='constant')
plt.imshow(im2.astype('uint8'))
```